# Get data usage on each connection

Tags: windows, networking

How can I measure the network usage on different connections I use separately in windows? This feature was there in Windows 8, but has been removed in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open Settings (or click Start and select Settings)
2. From there, click **Network & Internet**
3. Click **Data usage** (if not already selected).

You should see your active connections listed with a number next to them, indicating their respective data usage for the past 30 days. You can click **Usage details** to see how much data specific programs have been using.

If you are interested in the network utilization, open task manager and go to the Performance tab. Your active connections will be listed at the bottom.